# Schengen Tourist Visa from India

Tags: visas, schengen

I am looking forward to travel to Schengen countries from India (France, Germany, Netherland, Belgium). I have heard that visa success rate from North Indian is very low. So i have few queries : 
1. Which Schengen Country out of these have High Visa Success Rate?
2. Which Schengen Country emabassy have low funds requirements?

Answer (score 7):

The Schengen area has a **funds** requirement that is surprisingly low, and varies from state to state. The funds requirement is *just* to cover your subsistence in the Schengen area and it is around €50 per day, depending on the state.

But there is also a requirement for steady, well-documented **income and expenditures** which fit the usual lifestyle of a tourist or business traveler. [This excellent answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) talks about bank statements for UK visitors, but the principle is the same.

I believe that the funds requirement will not be much of a problem if you can meet the income/expenditure requirement.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, whichever country you apply you need to have a job or be a student with a convincing bank account. However, some countries are easier to convince.

Go for the Mediterranean countries such as Greece, Spain or Italy. Lately, France is also okay.

Edit: I am non-EU citizen and been living in EU for 5 years. The information above is based on my personal experience.